# How to create Flask-Stripe Checkout and Charge for the multiple items

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, stripe-payments

I am building an integration with Stripe by following the examples in its documentation, but I can't understand the part of creating a Charge for more than one product.

I was looking all over Stripe's docs and was searching for any articles / forums about the similar issue but was unable to find anything. I'd be very grateful to either some links to the articles on this matter or any tips to help me to understand how to solve it.

Here's a server side code:

````
```python
@app.route("/checkout", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def checkout():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Process a JSON string with a checkout information:
        # { item_id: item_quantity, ... }
        # Build the SQL query based on it
        items = {}
        shopping_cart = request.form["cart_checkout"]
        shopping_cart = shopping_cart.lstrip("{")
        shopping_cart = shopping_cart.rstrip("}")
        shopping_cart = shopping_cart.split(",")
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE item_id IN ("
        for KeyValPair in shopping_cart:
            Key = KeyValPair.split(":")[0]
            Key = Key.strip('"')
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery + Key + ","
            Value = KeyValPair.split(":")[1]
            items[Key] = Value
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.rstrip(",")
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery + ") ORDER BY item_id ASC"
        cart_items = sql_select(sqlQuery)

        # Add a column about the quantity of items
        for item in cart_items:
            item["quantity"] = items[item["item_id"]]

        # Build a Stripe checkout list
        line_items_list = []
        for item in cart_items:
            line_item = {}
            line_item["name"] = item["item_name"]
            line_item["description"] = item["item_description"]
            line_item["amount"] = item["price"]
            line_item["currency"] = "usd"
            line_item["quantity"] = item["quantity"]
            line_items_list.append(dict(line_item))

        stripe_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            submit_type="pay",
            payment_method_types=["card"],
            line_items=line_items_list,
            success_url='https://example.com/success',
            cancel_url='https://example.com/cancel',
        )

        return render_template("checkout.html",
            stripe_id=stripe_session.id,
            stripe_pk=stripe_keys["PUBLIC_KEY"])

    return redirect("/")
```
````

And here's a part of HTML template:

````
```html
<form action="/checkout" method="post" id="form_checkout" onsubmit="return cart_info()"
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_checkout" id="checkout_info" value="{{ cart_checkout }}">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="{{ stripe_pk }}"
        data-name="Company Name"
        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-description="A description of the product or service being purchased"
        data-amount="999"
        data-shipping-address="true"
        data-zip-code="true"
        data-allow-remember-me="true"
        data-panel-label="Pay"
        data-label="Checkout"
        data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>
```
````

If I do a simple example of Charge from Stripe docs, like this:

````
```python
@app.route('/charge', methods=['POST'])
def charge():
    # Amount in cents
    amount = 500

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email='customer@example.com',
        source=request.form['stripeToken']
    )

    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        customer=customer.id,
        amount=amount,
        currency='usd',
        description='Flask Charge'
    )

    return render_template('charge.html', amount=amount)
```
````

Then I can create without any issues a successful test Charge, it displays with the success label in my Stripe's dashboard. If I use `stripe.checkout.Session.create`, Stripe dashboard properly creates an incomplete record about my Checkout session with the selected list of items, but I've no idea how to proceed from there to finalise the Charge for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often happens, when I start asking questions, I eventually find the answers on my own, lol. I've had a `"checkout.html"` template but it didn't work, and no errors were displaying, so I assumed that I was missing some more code required for it all to work.

As it happened, all I was missing, was "" in a line of code. Here's a working Checkout session with the addition of a bit of JavaScript:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Checkout{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="wrapper main-content">

        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% for category, message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">{{ message }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endwith %}

        <h2 class="section-header">Checkout</h2>

        <p id="result_msg"></p>

        <button onclick="checkout()">Checkout</button>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkout() {
            var stripe = Stripe("{{ stripe_pk }}");

            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
                // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
                // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
                sessionId: "{{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}}"
            }).then(function (result) {
                // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                // using `result.error.message`.
                document.getElementById("result_msg").innerHTML = result.error.message;
            });
        }
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```